# Can't uninstall Ubuntu and install Mint

Tags: boot, bootloader

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10. I've "Mint" bootable CD. I just want to delete Ubuntu and Setup Mint.

Firstly, I inserted my "Mint" disk and rebooted my PC. The installtion didn't start. Then I changed my boot settings to CD; again, nothing happened.

How can I setup my Linux Mint bootable CD?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set your first boot device priority as CD Drive
2. Boot with your Ubuntu Live CD.
3. Select the option to "Try Ubuntu"
4. From the installed applications under "Dash/Main menu" Search for "Disk Manager"
5. Select your hard drive from which u want to remove ubuntu
6. Search for **Partition** on which ubuntu is installed
7. Delete the partition / Format it with "MBR" category
8. Reboot the system with Linux Mint CD this time
9. Follow the installation instruction for mint from this point.

**NOTE : Deleting a partition or using format option will completely wash the data off it. If you do this on complete hard drive then it will remove every bit of data on it. BE CAREFUL**